# MySqlBulkLoader SQL Injection Prevention

Tags: asp.net, mysql, security, sql-injection, bulkinsert

I am trying to allow users to upload CSV files to my database.  I was wondering if the MySqlBulkLoader prevents against SQL injection?

If not, what is the best way to parse the file and remove any sql injection code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to worry about SQL injections when using the MySQLBulkLoader class: this class just calls a `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement to process the CSV file, and it will not actually execute any queries from the CSV file. See [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-bulk-loader.html) on "Using the MySqlBulkLoader Class".

Comment: By using the MysqlBulkLoader is there any possibility a user can read other files on the MySQL Server?

Comment: Not if you design your upload script well. The class in itself won't randomly access other files on the server, so all you need to do is make sure your code is very clear about which file it needs to read. So just make sure that your code only passes on the name of the uploaded file, and you should be good. (If my answer was helpful to you, I'd appreciate it if you could accept it.)